# Trying to make a Paladin sorcerer build (sorcadin) that has good nova damage with hits like divine smite and magic from sorcerer

Tags: dnd-5e, multi-classing, sorcerer, paladin

I think what I'm trying to say is confusing but right now.

I am a level 5 Paladin and level 1 Sorcerer. I have been trying to find a good way of getting heavy-hitting spells and doing a lot of damage close as well.

I don't know where to start because I don't know a lot about D&D and chose paladin because it's fun. I chose sorcerer to be different and cannot decide which subclass is good, because all the ones I am finding is when you're level 18-20 when I need one probably a maximum level of 14.

If anyone can give me details on which paladin oath is best for this and subclass for sorcerer, that will be helpful.

Oath of Vengeance paladin with a greatsword, Great Weapon Master feat. I'm trying to lean into more tank but still doing a lot of damage at most moments.

Comment: Welcome to the stack Savage Duck!  Take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) when you have a moment, and feel free to peruse the [help](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) center for more in-depth info about the site.

Comment: Do you have the players handbook?  Are you already playing, or are you starting the game at level 6?  How many sessions have you played so far?  If you don't know much about D&D, can you explain why you started your first character as a multi classed character?

Comment: I do not and no we did not start at level 6. It was at level 3 I think and its has been about 6.  This is not my first character ( sorry for not clarifying), but I heard that most multiclass builds are stronger then just following the path.

Comment: You might want to clarify this statement:  "cannot decide which subclass is good, because all the ones I am finding is when you're level 18-20" . . . that doesn't make sense because all the sorcerer subclasses offer features at 1st, 6th, 14th, and 18th.

Comment: I meant all the strong multiclasses I have found are really late and my campaign will not go that far.

Comment: If you do not have the PHB, where are you getting your information on sorcerer subclasses?  There is only one in the basic rules.

Comment: Online like googaling what im trying to find.

Comment: "details on which paladin oath is best" . . . didn't you already pick Oath of Vengeance?

Comment: Yes, but for other campaigns so next time I have a better understanding on how to build what I want.

Comment: There are related questions here [1](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/184631/how-can-multiclassing-improve-my-lvl-9-paladin-oath-of-vengeance) and here [2](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/114308/is-playing-a-paladin-sorcerer-multi-class-viable)

Answer (score 5):

### Paladin 6 Sorcerer 8 will fit your needs through level 14.

"Which paladin class?" you have already answered with Oath of Vengeance.  That is a very combat focused oath with good class abilities to take advantage of smiting. Your *vow of enmity* leans into melee combat.

Clarification - Party includes also a rogue and a cleric.

#### Which Sorcerer subclass/origin?

Draconic Bloodline has some good features that you'll be able to put to use.

1. You'll get one form of elemental resistance based on the dragon type that you choose at level 6: fire, lightning, cold, poison, acid.  In mid to late Tier 2 and early tier 3, elemental damage from beings like dragons (Adult) and various elementals is well worth having resistance to.  While I'd suggest fire, cold and lightning aren't bad to choose. Depends on your campaign. If you are heading into the lower planes, the fire resistance is likely your best bet.
2. You get one more HP per hit die at level 1.  Since you want to tank, that may help.
3. You will have access to the shield spell at level 1.  That's a big benefit if you want to be in melee a lot.
4. You'll get spells up to level 4 and plenty of them, plus cantrips.  I'd suggest two ranged attack cantrips and two utility cantrips.
5. You'll have the paladin aura (level 6) that helps you and your party with saving throws.  That's far more important than stopping at level 5/9 sorcerer and going for the end game chance for a level 5 spell slot at level 14.
6. Balancing out when you use your spells to smite and when you use your spells for spell effects is going to be very campaign dependent, and very group dependent.  You will learn as you go.

#### An argument for Paladin 7 Sorcerer 7

You'll miss out on an ASI if you do this, so I'd be reluctant to suggest this, but for your purposes the level 7 Vengeance paladin ability fits part of your goals on the tanking and damaging side, ***but at a cost***.

- **Benefit**: being able to avoid opportunity attacks when you chase down an enemy who is trying to get away from you.  If you have to move around a lot on the battlefield to do this, not getting OA'd when you pursue like that may be what you need. It  may also allow you to stay engaged with an enemy so that your Rogue party ally gets sneak attack!
- **Cost**: this delays more spell slots, delays sorcerer class feature, and delays getting the next higher spell level slots by one level.

  - With this choice, you won't get level 4 spells until level 14.  (Freedom of Movement, for example, is a great level 4 spell that fits your idea...).  If you leave paladin at 6 you get that 4th level slot one level earlier, and you'll get your level 3 slots one level earlier.

Based on your question, that's a decision for later, after you get more sorcerer levels.  For the time being, getting that sixth level, and the aura, is as far as you need to go before you start adding more spells/sorcerer levels.

#### Meta Magic

How your party fights as a team will inform your choices here. You can, of course, use sorcery points to get more spell slots for smiting; that feeds into your goal of doing a lot of damage.

#### Misty Step

I want to draw your attention to the *misty step* spell.  Sometimes, you either need to get at a distant enemy, or to get out of a mess. *Misty step* is incredibly useful in any tactical situation.
My Watcher's paladin picked this up with a feat and used it a great many times.  My current Rune Knight picked it up with his Fey Touched feat.  You have it as an oath spell. For a melee character, having that bit of extra mobility is now and again a decisive difference in an encounter.

#### Hold Person

Fighting humanoids - when hold person lands and they don't make a save all of your hits are crits, and, all of your attacks are with advantage.  Even if you aren't casting it, if one of the other party members does then you need to coordinate with them.  You want to go nova? That's a way to go nova on a humanoid.
You made this comment under your question:

> Yes, but for other campaigns so next time I have a better
> understanding on how to build what I want.

#### Next campaign: Oath of the Watchers synergizes with any party

I recommend the Oath of the Watchers if you are willing to go to Paladin 7 in your next campaign.  Why?
The initiative boost for your party with the level 7 aura. I played a paladin of that oath to level 17.  The entire party had become addicted to the initiative boost by the end of our level seven adventures when we leveled up to 8.  It is based on your proficiency bonus, so at level 9 (Paladin 7 Sorcerer 2) you'll have a +4 boost, and at level 13 a +5 boost.

The sneaky benefit that the initiative boost offered to my paladin was that all of our PCs tended to go first, or at least early in the initiative order, which meant that various buffs and de-buffs went off before I attacked most of the time.  When *slow*, *blindness*, or other de-buffs on the opponents were already in place, my to-hit was often with advantage, or +2 (due to *slow* spell) more frequently.  Sure, sometimes we all rolled terribly and the +5 hardly mattered, but for most of our encounters the party was well ahead of the opponents during each round.  That's a non-trivial benefit in combat.

A general [Paladin/Sorcerer multiclass answer that may be helpful to you is here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/123247/22566).

#### What about Divine Soul sorcerer?

Source: *Xanathar's Guide to Everything*
You won't get an elemental resistance, and you won't get extra HP points with each level of Sorcerer, but you will get access to a variety of clerical spells that can help you heal or recover.  While I'd suggest the affinity to Law (Bless) or Neutral (Protection vs Evil and Good) any of them is a good pick depending on which alignment you choose an affinity for.

1. *Favored by the gods* is helpful (level 1) for your tanking or attack: you get to, once per short or long rest, roll a 2d4 to add onto a missed saving throw or attack.  Sometimes, you need that save versus a control spell cast by an enemy so that you can stay in the fight.  Sometimes, you just need to hit that opponent to finish it off this round ...
2. *Empowered Healing (level 6):* you can burn a sorcery point to re-roll a low die roll on a healing spell.  Useful in certain situations, but I think that the level 6 Draconic Bloodline ability is a bit better overall.  Our divine soul/fiend sorcerer/warlock (in a different campaign) used it with some frequency.

Comment: Will it be worth it to go 7 into paladin for relentless avenger or better to go into sorcerer for the spell slots?  Also this helped alot thank you very much!

Comment: Im pretty sure Oath of Vengeance gets misty step at level 5 because that's their oath, if I want to stay in fight more would relentless avenger do that?

Comment: Oh yeah sorry It is a Cleric, Rouge and me (paladin)

Comment: @Savageduck Thanks, I cleaned that up a bit, and I added the rogue plus cleric to context. Hope that's clearer. I still suggest you get a few more sorcerer levels before you decide unless you find that you are always chasing down enemies via OAs.